# Debugging not showing the proper result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn the javascript debugging and  I am followint the article here[linke here][1]

[1]: http://meeech.amihod.com/getting-started-with-javascript-debugging-in-chrome/ I was able to follow along the tutorial.My code is

```
<script>
    var value="hang";
    function test(){
            setInterval(function(){
        switch(value){
            case'hang':
            document.body.innerHtml="Hang in there";
            break;
            case'up':
            document.body.innerHTML="Up";
            break;
            default:
            document.body.innerHTML="No good!";         
            }
        },1000);
        };

</script>
```

Ater inspecting in debugger,it shows that it  reached to `document.body.innerHtml="Hang in there";`But my html page isnot showing the output **Hang in there**
Though it may seem simple question, I am not getting into it. Please help.
Also I cannot find **Add to watch option** on right click as stated in tutorial.

Comment: `it shows that it reached to` if the debugger is _on_ that line, then it hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: Is this some sort of test? you copy/pasted a block of code, and decided to arbitrarily change the case of 3 letters in the only case that would ever be fired, and left the other two instances of the same property alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS property names like `innerHTML` are case-sensitive. Try changing it to `….innerHTML="Hang in there"`.

Comment: Whoops, good catch! :)